# Querying information from the Windows Active Directory

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, active-directory

Is there a possibility to query information from the AD in c++?

I'm especially interested in the value of the second field of "***User logon name (pre-Windows 2000):***" on the "***Account***" tab.

Other languages would also be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can either use ADSI (via COM) or LDAP (via the wldap32 library) as two starting points. The attribute you want is called `sAMAccountName`.